# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-integration, classnotfoundexception

I am using spring-integration in my project. When I deploy my app in the jetty container, I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundhttpJobRequestGateway': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at com.dsths.spring.web.DsthsContextLoaderListener.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(DsthsContextLoaderListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.dsths.common.container.core.deploy.DeploymentManager.deploy(DeploymentManager.java:54)
    at com.dsths.common.container.core.deploy.DeploymentManager$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f5bc43eb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundhttpJobRequestGateway': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.detectHandlerMethods(IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.<init>(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.<init>(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.dsths.common.container.ContainerClassLoader.loadClass(ContainerClassLoader.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
    ... 58 more
```

I have both the jars `jackson-core-asl-1.8.3` and `jackson-core-2.3.1` in the class path. Still I am getting the error. How to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting what is `com.dsths.common.container.ContainerClassLoader`...

Looks like `spring-integration-http` is loaded by this `ClassLoader`, but `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and all others `spring-web` classes with another `ClassLoader`.

Would be great, if you place all spring jars within the same class loader.

The app is not able to find MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in the class path. The problem is one class loader is picking one version  and another class loader is picking another version.

Comment: I have `jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar` in the class path.Do I need to have `jackson-core-asl-2` in the class path too?

Comment: Forget that. I've changed my answer. Sorry: hadn't looked to your StackTrace properly

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am using custom jetty container. `com.dsths.common.container.ContainerClassLoader` is part of the custom container. is having conflicting versions of jars lead to the above problem?

Comment: No-no. There is no version conflicts. All spring jar should be at the same place, because, as we see, different classloader don't see all classes

Comment: Artem Bilan, how to place all spring jars within the sama class loader? Could you please elaborate more? Actually, my container has a `lib/container` folder where all jars are placed. The class loader will load all those jars.Still wondering how two class loaders are involved in this?because only one class loader should be there I guess.

Comment: Actually they should be placed in the `WEB-INF/lib`, because you say that you use custom classloader.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I was on vacation for all these days.Yes, you are almost correct. The problem here is I have Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE JARS under my WEB-INF/lib, and my container has  3.2.4.RELEASE version. So, due to this conflict, my app is unable to find MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. When I upgraded spring jar versions to 3.2.4.RELEASE from 3.1.1.RELEASE, the problem is solved.

Comment: Artem Bilan, +1 for your continuous support.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, the class `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` exists in `spring-web.jar` (or `spring-web-x.y.z-RELEASE.jar`), you should add it to your classpath, or if using maven add following dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Edit per Artem Bilan comment :

Normally, if you use maven, it should be present as a dependency of `spring-integration-http`, provided you have this one.

Comment: `spring-web` is a required transitive dependency of `spring-integration-http`. And if you use correctly dependency managemet tool it should be there anyway.

Comment: @ArtemBilan : you are right, but the error message suggests it is not there ;-) But I change last part of my answer that is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, it saved my time

Answer (score 3):

I had this weird error, too.  I did a search in my jars in the web server's (tomcat) webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib and the class was there -- and only once.

It went away when I looked at another project at my job and used the same jackson jars.

Originally, I had the following:

```
jackson-core-2.4.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.4.3.jar
```

I removed these and added the following (packaged into my WEB-INF/lib):

```
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.5.0.jar
jackson-datatype-joda-2.5.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core-2.5.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
```

I'm running this on Tomcat 7 on windows; using Java 1.6 (for compiling and runtime in Tomcat)

**servlet.xml:**

```
<beans:bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"  
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" >
</beans:bean>

    <beans:bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

In case it helps, I run the following shell from cygwin for searching for jats

```
JAR="C:/java/Java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/jar.exe"
srchdir="c:/appservers/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/my-web/WEB-INF/lib"

echo "SEARCH FOLDER: $srchdir"
find  $srchdir -print | grep '\.jar$' | while read f
do
    $JAR tf $f | grep 'MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter\.class' >/dev/null 2>&1
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "==> $f" && $JAR tf $f | grep MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter\.class
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's a jar package problem. You can't find this method in the jar package you imported. You should replace it with another jar package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).