# Class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am getting the following error in the `servlet-context.xml`. I am [following the following tutorial to get this done](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program).

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   not found
>     - Class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   not found [config set: myapp/web-      context]

```
<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140993/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-http-converter-json-mappin

Comment: I just created the project and added those lines as suggested in the tutorial. I don't understand where to place the JAR files, since i have not added any. HELP

Comment: To add a jar to your class-path right-click on your project then configure build path and add external jar.

Comment: Sorry but i am beginner. but from where can i download the mission JAR ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add spring-web.jar in your classpath or if you are using maven then you should add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>X.Y.Z.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```